# CLI free memory for composer

Tags: php, composer-php, command-line-interface, memory-limit

Is there a shell command to find out how much memory composer can use at the cli SAPI? Not the CGI one which can be found by performing a phpinfo();

I would like to know the memory limit my hoster has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line:

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
```

Read about memory limit errors [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors).